# all of my rest api endpoints are secured by default, how can i unsecure them ?(jersey)

Tags: rest, api, jakarta-ee, jersey-2.0

i've been working with jersey rest api for a while now, something new and weird happened to me. suddenly all of my endpoint are secured.i used the @Secure Annotation. and even if i delete it from my endpoint i still need authorization to access the resource have tried to access via postman, intellij rest client and chrome as a browser.
here is an example of a resource

```
package com.leaders.bo;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
@Path("/majd")
public class majdResource {

/**
 * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
 * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
 *
 * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
 */
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getIt() {
    return "Got it!";
}
@PUT
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getIt2() {
    return "Got it!";
}
@DELETE
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getIt3() {
    return "Got it!";
}
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getIt4() {
    return "Got it!";
}
}
```

and here is the name binding for the annotation 
    package com.leaders.bo.Resources;

```
import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

/**
 * Created by Majd on 8/1/2017.
*/
@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Secured { }
```

and here is my authenticationFilter
    package com.leaders.bo.Resources;

```
import com.leaders.bo.dao.TokensDao;
import com.leaders.bo.dao.posDao;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;
import javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.SignatureException;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

/**
 * Created by Majd on 8/1/2017.
 */
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    // Get the HTTP Authorization header from the request
    String authorizationHeader =
            requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    // Check if the HTTP Authorization header is present and formatted correctly
    if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("ey")) {
        throw new NotAuthorizedException("Authorization header must be provided");
    }

    // Extract the token from the HTTP Authorization header
    final String token = authorizationHeader.substring("".length()).trim();


    try {

        // Validate the token
        validateToken(token,TokensDao.getCompanyNameFromToken(token));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        requestContext.abortWith(
                Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
    }
    final SecurityContext currentSecurityContext = requestContext.getSecurityContext();
    requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {

        @Override
        public Principal getUserPrincipal() {

            return new Principal() {

                @Override
                public String getName() {
                    return token;
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSecure() {
            return currentSecurityContext.isSecure();
        }


        //returns the company name that the token is a part of.
        @Override
        public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
            return TokensDao.getCompanyNameFromToken(token);
        }
    });
}
private void validateToken(String token,String companyName) throws Exception {
    // Check if it was issued by the server and if it's not expired
    // Throw an Exception if the token is invalid
    if(!posDao.validateToken(token,companyName))
        throw new SignatureException();
}
```

}

but still for some reason every new endpoint i create i get a secured endpoint even if i dont use the @secured annotation, i invalidated the cache and restarted, rebuilt the application and deleted the source target, and still it didnt help.
anyone got an idea how to help ?
thanks allot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `@Secured` annotation on the filter class also. This is how [Name Binding works](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9675). You bind the method to the filter. If the filter is not annotated, the filter will run for all endpoints. This is probably what was happening before, and you just *though* it was because of the annotation (that you probably had on all your endpoints).

Comment: Thanks allot, Worked fine. sorry i don't have up votes yet but once i have i'll up vote your answer :)